# How to inherit the standard output to a child process efficiently in java?

Tags: java, process, exec, pipe, io-redirection

In Java, I want to invoke the `grep` command and send its output to the stdout. I can do this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "regexp", "foo.txt");
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.start().waitFor();
```

However, the stdout of the `grep` process is actually **piped** to the java process and then printed. This can be inefficient when the data is huge.

A dirty way is to find the stdout of the java process (e.g. by `readlink(/proc/self/fd/1)`) and then call `pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(new File(MYSTDOUTFILE)));`, but is there a better way?

Comment: Sounds like JRuby dealt with [similar issues](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/13381)